# Export MSSQL and Oracle database data with SSH

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, ssh, backup

How can I export the data in the database of MSSQL Server and Oracle using SSH to connnect?

Is it possible for me to type some command and export the data into, for example, a text file?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For oracle you achieve this by using sqlplus to connect to the database and query the data. The results can be written to a file with the spool command

```
sqlplus user/passwd
spool exp.txt
select * from bla
sppol off
quit
```